# How to remove 'Warning: Async Storage has been extracted from react-native core...'?

Tags: react-native

I've already tried what's recommended in this screenshot

[image: Screenshot-20190323-081232.png]

by using this line of code
`import AsyncStorage from '../../../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage';` in the file where I'm importing `async-storage` from `react-native`
but this path is unresolved, i.e. `async-storage` doesn't exist in this directory. I also tried installing `async-storage` (even though it's already installed) by running `yarn add async-storage`, but nothing appeared in the previously mentioned directory

Comment: Did you try to install exactly what was mentioned, that is `@react-native-community/async-storage`?

Comment: Have you tried to use directly this import instead of ../../../node..... ? : import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

Comment: Yes, I did. It  threw this [error](https://postimg.cc/VJHNbC6W)

Comment: Hi, I got this not from my direct dependency but from my dependency's dependency. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried installing AsyncStorage according to Andrew's answer?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.

- Firstly import `AsyncStorage` correctly. This will remove the warning and fix the problem.
- Secondly, suppress the warning. This will just hide the warning but will cause you issues once `AsyncStorage` has been removed from `react-native`. I **would not** do this as the first way actually solves the problem.

> **Note** you can get this warning if you are using a dependency that uses AsyncStorage and still imports it the old way from react-native. **Installing AsyncStorage won’t fix the error.** You will need to look through your dependencies’ dependencies to find out which one is causing it.
>
> This means actually going through the code of each your dependencies to see if they use `AsyncStorage`. Searching through your node modules or on the dependency's Github usually is sufficient but it can take some time to find it.
>
> Once you have found out which one is causing it, you should open an issue or create a PR with a fix on the dependency’s repo. At this point suppressing the warning is all you can do until it is fixed.

## Install AsyncStorage

1. Install it using your favourite package manager `npm` or `yarn`
2. Link the dependency
3. Use the dependency

Installation: choose the method you usually use

```
npm i @react-native-community/async-storage
```

or

```
yarn add @react-native-community/async-storage
```

Link the dependency (you may not have to do this if you are using 0.60+ as it has [Autolinking](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md))

```
react-native link @react-native-community/async-storage
```

Then you import it like this, and use it as before.

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

You can see more about it by looking [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage/blob/master/README.md)

## Suppress the warning.

Previously you would use `YellowBox` to suppress warnings, this has now changed to [LogBox](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#logbox). The process is similar to that of `YellowBox`

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';
```

Then you can add the following

```
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Warning: Async Storage has been extracted from react-native core']);
```

I usually do it in the `App.js` so it is easy to keep track of which ones I have hidden.

It won't remove the warning from your console, but it will remove any LogBox warnings associated with the error. **However, I wouldn’t do this on this occasion as there is a proper fix, which is to install the dependency correctly.**

---

## Expo users

Currently Expo still imports `AsyncStorage` from `react-native`, due to this you may still experience the warning. I believe it still imports it this way for backwards compatibility reasons. A quick search of the Expo repo shows that there are many instances where it is used as you can see [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/search?q=asyncstorage%20from%20%27react-native%27&unscoped_q=asyncstorage%20from%20%27react-native%27). In this case your only option would be to suppress the warning. According to the Expo feature requests it is [currently in progress](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/continued-support-for-asyncstorage), so hopefully it should be added to Expo shortly.

## Expo Update

As of June 2020: `@react-native-community/async-storage` v1.11.0 can be installed in Expo managed apps. Hopefully this will lead to less of these warnings appearing as dependencies transition to the new way of importing async-storage.

## Repo update

There is now a new repository for async-storage which can be found here

https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage

Check out the documentation for installation and linking instructions

https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/

Comment: definitely do not put that in your `render` method! `YellowBox.ignoreWarnings` does a whole lot of iterations over collections, putting it in the `render` is a terrible idea (`render` is too hot!). You only want it to execute once, I would maybe put it in `componentDidMount`, perhaps wrapping it in `lodash.once`

Comment: Suppressing the warning is not an answer. The warning should not be showing in the first place. I too tried to install it using the methods you described but it does not remove the warning.

Comment: @Hasen have you removed all instances of `import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native` and replaced them with `import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'` as you may have missed one which will cause you to still get the warning?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue as Hasen.

Comment: @Simon if you’ve updated all your instances of where you are using Async-Storage to the correct import then it could be caused by a dependency that uses Async-Storage.

Comment: Yes, I ended up figuring out that I use `react-native-elements` which depends on `react-native-ratings` which has `expo` as a dependency. Unfortunately, the latest version of `expo` still relies on an import of AsyncStorage from `react-native` as you can see here: https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/packages/expo/src/Notifications/Notifications.ts

Comment: As @Simon mentions above, Expo users must still load AsyncStorage from react-native, because expo doesn't yet support packages that require linking.

Comment: @Simon thanks, would upvote but missclicked and removed an upvote so I can never upvote your comment again.

Silly dependencies need updates.

Comment: Seems like `@react-native-community/async-storage` is now deprecated

Comment: To suppress the warning:

1 - import {LogBox} from 'react-native'; 
instead of importing  YellowBox

2 -  LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Warning: Async Storage has been extracted from react-native core']) instead of YellowBox..ignoreWarnings

Answer (score 11):

If the source of the issue is Firebase then a working solution as of version 9.9.2 is to set the default persistence layer used by Firebase to store the authentication session to be AsyncStorage after correctly importing it:

`expo install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage`

then to add in firebase.js

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence} from 'firebase/auth/react-native';
```

and then to export { auth } via

```
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage)
});

export { auth };
```

Unlike getAuth(), initializeAuth() gives us control over the persistence layer .

[Reference](https://amanhimself.dev/blog/remove-asyncstorage-has-been-extracted-warning-using-firebase/).

Comment: This is the right solution for Firebase, and works.To add more references, it was introduced here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1847#issuecomment-863411833 and I also liked the single-loading trick from this comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1847#issuecomment-1041548028

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be an ongoing issue on Firebase with React Native.

Check out this thread:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1847

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30502676)

Comment: @essam explains the eventual solution to this in their answer

Answer (score 4):

For me this issue was with @firebase.

> node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.rn.cjs.js

following the steps above from Andrew, in vscode I was able to remove the warning.

1. copy "AsyncStorage"
2. cmd + shift + f - then paste "AsyncStorage" into search
3. click three dots under search '...'
4. right click node_modules folder select 'copy path'
5. add path to 'files to include' in vscode search
6. find one example of the import or require statement for the original (incorrect) AsyncStorage, copy that. Paste it into the search, replacing the first search query.

Once all the imports are found install the AsyncStorage correctly for the new version (as mentioned above), also add to pods, then go through and replace all

```
require('react-native').AsyncStorage; => require('@react-native-community/async-storage').AsyncStorage;

import AsyncStorage from 'react-native'; => import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

I did a clean build with xcode, Then all was good to go, no more warning :-)

Comment: This won’t permanently solve the problem. It is only a temporary fix. The issue with this is that when you reinstall your node_modules or your pods you will have to perform the above steps again.

Comment: There is definitely an issue with Firebase (Firebase Auth, in particular). I got the warning to go away by digging into the Firebase code and replacing the imports as described above. But when I did, local persistence of auth data no longer worked. So I ended up putting everything back the way it was and just suppressing the warning. It doesn't feel ideal, but at least everything in the Firebase Auth works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I have been annoyed by this similar issue and here is my [warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyprF.png). I simply solved it by:

- go to: 'node_modules/react-native/index.js'
- simply comment out all the lines that contains 'AsyncStorage'
- Then it was working fine for me.

Comment: Thank you! That is literally all I wanted lol

Answer (score 0):

if you're using npm

```
npm install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

yarn

```
yarn add @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

Answer (score 0):

Credits to @Rory for the below steps:

Note: We need to find `var reactNative = require('react-native')` in `node_modules`

Note: If you don't want to do the following steps, just navigate to `node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/rn/index.js`

1. cmd + shift + f - then paste `var reactNative = require('react-native')` into search
2. click three dots under search '...'
3. right click `node_modules` folder select `copy path`
4. add path to `files to include` in vscode search

Then in `index.js` where we find our search, do the following replacements:

```js
// var reactNative = require('react-native');
var AsyncStorage = require('@react-native-async-storage/async-storage');

// and further below

// var reactNativeLocalPersistence = getReactNativePersistence(reactNative.AsyncStorage);
var reactNativeLocalPersistence = getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage);
```

Refresh and the warning is gone!

Answer (score 0):

`YellowBox` has been replaced with `LogBox`. You can use `LogBox.ignoreLogs()` instead to suppress the warning

Answer (score 0):

In my case firebase using asyn storage from react native . I am using v8 firebase which has no getReactNativePersistence.

So I had this solution which may be helpful.

**Keep below code snippet in one file ignoreWarning.js and import in App.js on top of file .**

```
import { LogBox } from "react-native";

const ignoreWarns = [
    "AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native",
];

const warn = console.warn;

console.warn = (...arg) => {

    for (const warning of ignoreWarns) {
        if (arg[0].startsWith(warning)) {
            return;
        }
    }
    warn(...arg);
};

LogBox.ignoreLogs(ignoreWarns);
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's working, I can try it.**

```
// With npm:

npm install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage

// With Yarn:

yarn add @react-native-async-storage/async-storage

// With Expo CLI:

npx expo install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage

// Usage
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', value);
await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key');
```

https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage/