# COMPONENT has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from NEW LOCATION

Tags: react-native

I am getting this warning messages in my chrome console logs for my react-native up. They suddenly started popping. Actually, more than 1 warning messages like this.

> Warning: Async Storage has been extracted from the react-native core and
>   will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and
>   imported from '@react-native-community/async-storage' instead of
>   'react-native'.
>
> Warning: Slider has been extracted from the react-native core and will be
>   removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from
>   '@react-native-community/slider' instead of 'react-native'.
>
> Warning: ViewPagerAndroid has been extracted from react-native core
>   and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and
>   imported from '@react-native-community/viewpager' instead of
>   'react-native'.

I think these messages are being displayed whether or not you are using/importing those components in your app, right? Because I am not using, for example, *async storage* anywhere on my app. Maybe some 3rd party libraries that I installed on my app are using them?

What are the actions that I should take?

Thanks

Comment: are you use redux or redux-persist in your app?

Comment: figure out which libraries are using them,  file issue or make a pull request and change their code accordingly.

Comment: @novonimo yes, actually I do use redux. Do you think it uses async storage? then I should update the redux library to get rid of the first warning?

Comment: @JaydeepGalaniany Any actual "helpful" comments so that people who visit this page in the future can actually get some benefit from them? Like novonimo has done.

Comment: see this video from dan_abramov:
https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage

Comment: you can see a resolution of this problem there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55311388

Comment: You can see the solution there https://stackoverflow.com/a/55311388