# How to resolve using AsyncStorage (deprecated) warning? Using the community (correct) library

Tags: react-native, warnings, asyncstorage

I am using @react-native-community/async-storage and keep receiving this warning:

`Warning: Async Storage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage`

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mobile_app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/pushnotification": "^1.0.32",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "aws-amplify": "^1.1.32",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^2.1.15",
    "buffer": "^5.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.9",
    "react-native-ble-plx": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.208.0",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-dialog": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.5.0",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-swipeable-row": "^0.8.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have deleted node_modules, and yarn.lock and reinstalled. Also, I looked through all my dependencies (as was recommended in this question: [How to remove 'Warning: Async Storage has been extracted from react-native core...'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55311228/how-to-remove-warning-async-storage-has-been-extracted-from-react-native-core)) and none of them use the deprecated async storage package.

Do you have any suggestions for how to resolve this warning?

---- Edit:
I was asked how I import AsyncStorage. I only do it in one place in a file called storage-helpers:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

set_data = async (storage_key, value) => {
    try {
        const value_to_store = JSON.stringify(value);
        return await AsyncStorage.setItem(storage_key, value_to_store);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
    }
}

get_data = async (storage_key) => {
    console.log("Getting Data", storage_key);
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(storage_key)
        .then((returned_value) => {
            const parsed = JSON.parse(returned_value);
            return parsed;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Get Item Error: ", error);
        })
    console.log("Finished Getting Data");
    return value;
}

clear_data = async () => {
    console.log("Clearing Persistent Storage");
    return await AsyncStorage.clear();
}

module.exports = {
    set_data,
    get_data,
    clear_data,
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Update

There is now a new repository for async-storage which can be found here

https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage

Usage **(note the new name of the dependency)**:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
```

Check out the documentation for installation, linking instructions, and usage.

https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/

https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage

——

Looking at your list of dependencies, the first one on your list `@aws-amplify/pushnotification` uses `AsyncStorage` from `react-native`

You can see [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/pushnotification/src/PushNotification.ts#L14) that it imports `AsyncStorage`. Below is the exact line:

```
import { NativeModules, DeviceEventEmitter, AsyncStorage, PushNotificationIOS, Platform, AppState } from 'react-native';
```

This will be why you are getting the warning, it is due to this dependency using `AsyncStorage`

There was an issue that had been opened by in May about this, however it has since been marked closed. You can see the issue [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3209).

---

It seems that `@aws-amplify/core` also uses `AsyncStorage` from `react-native`.

You can see it being used in the RNComponents [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/core/src/RNComponents/reactnative.ts), and in the StorageHelper [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/core/src/StorageHelper/reactnative.ts).

---

Your best course of action is to fork the repo and fix all instances of AsyncStorage to use the correct version, or open an issue.

---

It is always worth going through your dependencies carefully to see what they are actually using. Sometimes just searching what they have installed or what is on their github can be enough.

Comment: I am noting your suggestion to carefully search through each of the dependencies, because looking only though their list of dependencies was not sufficient. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you're using the correct import:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. That is how I import it, and I only do it in one file. I added the code above.

Comment: I went through each of the packages in my dependencies and looked at their package.json and non imported AsyncStorage. Would you recommend looking anywhere else? Thanks for your help.

Comment: yeah sorry, just reread your question and saw that.  I don't have any suggestions other than doing a global search to confirm that it isn't being imported somewhere else.

Comment: I have done global search in VSCode and found nothing unfortunately, and no worries, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

seems Async Storage moved to new organization

[image]

try
`npm i  @react-native-async-storage/async-storage`

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
```

Answer (score 2):

Get library with one of the below command

With npm:

```
npm install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

With Yarn:

```
yarn add @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

With Expo CLI:

```
expo install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

**Once done, import the header**

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
```

**For store a value**

```
const storeData = async (value) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', value)
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
  }
}
```

**Get a Value**

```
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
    if(value !== null) {
      // value previously stored
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}
```

For more: [offical link](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage)

Answer (score 0):

Check if one of your dependencies uses Async Storage and they're importing it directly from react.