# AsyncStorage are deprecated using React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mqtt, asyncstorage

I'm trying to use MQTT on freact native so I had to use AsyncStorage in my code when I try to import it from react native it was deprecated. any help please.

```
 import init from 'react-native-mqtt'
 import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'

init({
  size: 10000,
  storageBackend: AsyncStorage,
  defaultExpires: 1000 * 3600 * 24,
  enableCache: true,
  reconnect: true,
  sync : {
  }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve using AsyncStorage (deprecated) warning? Using the community (correct) library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57578179/how-to-resolve-using-asyncstorage-deprecated-warning-using-the-community-cor)

Answer (score 4):

Yes [AsyncStorage](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage) is deprecated and they advice to use one of its community packages for implementing async storage. Also there is another key-value pair storage type which is called mmkv, said to be faster than AsyncStorage.

Check this link out for Community Packages for AsyncStorage
https://reactnative.directory/?search=storage

Answer (score 1):

AsyncStorage is now separated from React Native. Here is the new repo docs:

https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/

Usage:

```
import init from 'react-native-mqtt'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

init({
  size: 10000,
  storageBackend: AsyncStorage,
  defaultExpires: 1000 * 3600 * 24,
  enableCache: true,
  reconnect: true,
  sync : {
  }
});
```