# React Native Expo shows Async Storage warning

Tags: react-native

i'm using React Native expo, and it shows

**[Warning: Async Storage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage].**

i read this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55311228/how-to-remove-warning-async-storage-has-been-extracted-from-react-native-core?noredirect=1&lq=1) and I understood that it's due to the fact that some dependencies are using old AsyncStorage, not the new one from community.
But I hardly found that any solution for Expo users. Is there any solution for Expo? Or if I have to manual change dependencies using the old AsyncStorage, how can i do it? Since I'm new to React Native, not really sure what to do..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Expo you should always link the libraries that Expo includes in the App. So like mentioned in the docs here https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/async-storage/

`expo install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage`

is the correct import. If you are working with an old Expo-SDK this might be different, otherwise you should adapt your imports.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I downloaded async-storage through the expo install command. will it automatically link to the new async?
for example, Im using firebase and it shows the warning. Will this async-storage automatically change from the old to the new? or I have to do something to link?

Comment: Firebase is not completely included in Expo (normal) but can be used with EAS or with an ejected/bare project, if you use the latest versions installed with expo install expo would usually take care of compatibility. You should check the Expo-Documentation on firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Now expo has migrated to use as well the [community version](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage)  as you can see [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/async-storage/).

But if you get this warning definitely you have some dependency or more that still use the react-native-core version, if so please refer to the first answer to [How to resolve using AsyncStorage (deprecated) warning? Using the community (correct) library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57578179/how-to-resolve-using-asyncstorage-deprecated-warning-using-the-community-cor):

if this is the case the **best** is as suggested in that answer is to

> Your best course of action is to fork the repo and fix all instances of AsyncStorage to use the correct version, or open an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because firebase imports AsyncStorage from react native core and not the new library @react-native-async-storage/async-storage. I think firebase hasn't updated the by default import yet so you have to do it yourself.The way I fixed it was ;

- Install react-native-async-storage: npm i @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
- Go into the firebase index.js file that imports AsyncStorage from react native core: It is located at : 'node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/rn'.
- Create a variable that imports AsycnStorage from 'node-modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage' :
  var AsyncStorage = require('../../../../@react-native-async-storage/async-storage');
- Replace all uses of AsyncStorage in this file from react native core with new variable, i.e. replace "ReactNative__namespace.AsyncStorage" with "AsycnStorage",

Answer (score 0):

**it's working, You can try it.**

```
npx expo install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage

// Usage
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', value);
await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key');
```

https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install