# Error in Metro Bundler: 'AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed....'

Tags: react-native, async-await, react-redux

I am getting the  error in metro bundler as mentioned in Title but I am not using Async anywhere or I did not import Async from anywhere (not even from react native core).
Below are my imports

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
```

[Screen Shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kUcd.png)
I have checked this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55311228/how-to-remove-warning-async-storage-has-been-extracted-from-react-native-core) already but as I have not used the Async directly in my code so this does not completely solves the error

Comment: Just be sure that all of your third party libraries in their latest versions.

Comment: @firats I have re installed all my packages but still I get the same error, I am unable to understand whats the problem here

Comment: Maybe you should try to search for  `import AsyncStorage` in your  `node_modules` for any case. Only reason you get this error one of your library uses the asyncstorage I think.

Comment: I found this line in in node_modules/@firebase var AsyncStorage = require('react-native').AsyncStorage; I think this is creating the problem

Comment: Yes probably, change it manually to `import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'` or update your firebase version.